# Syntax parameter in $.ajax and first load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like display my data following a tag select.

I fill the select tag with javascript method, hier it works well.

First : I want to pass in parameter the selectedindex value for my web service methode. But I have the error : 
[image]

How do I have to write the parameter?
Here is the javascript code :

```
function getStatistic3() {

var response;
var allstat3 = [];
var e = document.getElementById("Select1");
var kla = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3',
    data: { klant: kla },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.d;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
            var j = 0;
            allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
        }
        fillDataTable(allstat3);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error loading statistic 3");
    }
});
}
function fillSlectTag() {
var response;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3_All_Klant',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.d;
        var sel = document.getElementById('Select1');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = response[i];
            opt.value = response[i];
            sel.appendChild(opt);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error loading select stat3");
    }
});
}
```

Second : When I load the html page for the first time, it loads with null because I have not yet chosen the klant in the select tag.
How to fix this?

**Edit :**
@Talspaugh27

Here my html code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });
    });

    fillSlectTag();
</script>
</head>
<body>    

<select id="Select1" name="D1"><option></option></select>
 <script >
            $(".Select1").change(function () { getStatistic3(); });
</script>
<table id="table_campaigns" class="display">
    <caption style="font-size:20px">Statistiek 3 : per klant en productgroep</caption>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And javascript code :

```
function fillSlectTag() {
var response;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3_All_Klant',
    //data: data2Send,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.d;
        var sel = document.getElementById('Select1');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = response[i];
            opt.value = response[i];
            sel.appendChild(opt);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error loading select stat3");
    }
});
}

function getStatistic3() {

var response;
var allstat3 = [];
var e = document.getElementById("Select1");
var kla = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (kla) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3',
        data: JSON.stringify({ klant: kla }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            response = msg.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
            }
            fillDataTable(allstat3);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error loading statistic 3");
        }
    });
}
}

function showStatistic3() {
$("#contentCamp").empty();
$.ajax({
    url: 'Statistic_3.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#contentCamp").html(data);
        getStatistic3();
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Error loading statistic 3 html : " + e.statusText);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having the full app to test I think this should take care of both of your problems Will Explain each change after the code bit

```
function getStatistic3() {

var response;
var allstat3 = [];
var e = document.getElementById("Select1");
var kla = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if (kla) 
{
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3',
data: JSON.stringify({ klant: kla }),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (msg) {
    response = msg.d;
    for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
        var j = 0;
        allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j],     response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
    }
    fillDataTable(allstat3);
},
error: function (e) {
    alert("error loading statistic 3");
}
});
}
}
```

I wrapped the .ajax call in the if statement to capture whether a value is selected from your drop down and when you pass the data to the service Use the JSON.stringify to make sure that it properly wraps and escapes the data to something the service and javascript can mutually use.

HTH

T

Comment: I have this erro when I change select value : Message "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'klant'."

Comment: You should be able to use

$( ".Select1" ).change(function() {
  getStatistic3();
});

Comment: I would use the Dev tools in the browser to view what the post looks like go into Dev tools view network and start capturing, when you load the page you should see the call to your webservice, make sure you see the proper values posting to that service.

Comment: Where do I put this code? I put in script tag in my html page, is that it?

Comment: I put the code but when i change the select value, nothing happens, it doesn't call getStatistic3(). 

My html code is:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });
        });

        fillSlectTag();
    </script>
</head>
<body>    

    <select id="Select1" name="D1"><option></option></select>
    <script >
    $( ".Select1" ).change(function() { getStatistic3(); });
    </script>
    <table ...>
     ...
</html>

Comment: Make sure the getstatistic3 function is also before your rederence to it. I usually put my action captures at the bottom of the page

Comment: When you say the getStatistic3 function, you speak about function in ma javascript file?

I have a problem with firebug, when I want to see with debug, there are not my javascript file, as if the debug doesn't see. What' wrong?

Comment: I have Message "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'klant'." when I put a correct value in klant.

Comment: yes the Javascript file or script tag containing the getStatistic3 function should be placed before the references to it. As far as the Firebug, I dont use firefox that much but it looks like the debugger tab will allow you to look through all the attached javascripts.

Comment: and you have added the JSON.stringify({ klant: kla }), area from my answer?

Comment: The event "change" doesn't work and even if it works, I think that I would have an error with "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'klant'."

Comment: I dont Have the rep to comment on your code, but I dont see where the functions are being declared or referenced in that code? Is this what you were saying about firebug? if the files are in a .js file make sure you have a script tag with the appropriate src on it

Comment: after this line `code` 
if (kla) 
{
`code` add an alert(kla) and see what value you are getting at that point maybe to begin diagnosing

Comment: I have a html page that is the index and the all references are there.
there are buttons that call other html pages including this one

Comment: I added en else clause with alert for the if(kla), and the first time, the alert displays "null"

Comment: The other times, when I change the select tag value, it doesn't call the function getStatistic_3

Comment: Yeah I just noticed I put the wrong selector on that, should have been 
$( "#Select1" ).change(function() { getStatistic3(); }); the previous one was looking for a CLASS called Select1

Comment: Yes it works and now, as i said before, I have Message "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'klant'."

Comment: I created a jsfiddle to how it should be laid out and that the base code is working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VsEzq/1/)

Comment: The Stringify should be working for you, can you post the declaration for your webservice?

Comment: [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public ResponseStatistic_3 Statistic_3(string klant)
        {
                Statistic_3[] items = Helper.Helper_Statistic_3(klant).ToArray();
                ResponseStatistic_3 response = new ResponseStatistic_3(items);
                return response;
            }

Comment: I have an other method statistic_2 that returns too a responseStatistic and it works well. I think the problem is that statistic_3 method has a parameter and statistic_2 hasn't parameter.

Comment: If you hardcode the following line 
data: JSON.stringify({ klant: kla }),
to 
data: JSON.stringify({ klant: 'somevalidKlantValue' }),
does your webservice call work?

Comment: I added this : data: JSON.stringify({ klant: "Abdominale Heelkunde Herselt" }), and I have the same error.

Comment: Ok try the same line but remove the JSON.Stringify() part of it. 

We Will get this figured out lol

Comment: I found, it was just --> data: "klant='" + $('#Select1').val() + "'". Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the webservice expects json, which you aren't sending( you're sending url encoded form data)

Use JSON.encode to convert your data to JSON

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3',
    data: JSON.stringify({ klant: kla }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.d;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
            var j = 0;
            allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
        }
        fillDataTable(allstat3);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error loading statistic 3");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have this : TypeError: JSON.encode is not a function

Comment: @Jayce sorry its `stringify` not `encode` see update.

Comment: It works now but I want to refresh when I change the selecte value. How to fix it? I put the "onchange event on my select tag but it doesn't work.